# Using Rails model to update to change one boolean value based on another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to make a pet rails app. My pet model includes two boolean values, hungry and feed_me. Right now, hungry and feed_me can both be set in the view, but I'm trying to set up the model so that if feed_me is true, hungry will automatically be changed to false. No matter what I do, however, feed_me never resets hungry. This is what I have in the model now:

```
    attr_accessor :feed_me
    before_save :feed


     def feed
       @feed_me = Creature.find(params[:feed_me])
       @hungry=Creature.find(params[:hungry])
       if @feed_me==true
         @hungry=false
       end 
    end
```

I'm new to Rails, but my understanding is that model should have access to the params hash, so I'm confused about why I can't use it to reset values.

Comment: Do you need the :feed_me column? You can simplify your Creature model by just having a :hungry boolean column. If :feed_me, for example, is something that happens only after a creature has been :hungry for 5 hours, then that's something you can just calculate on the fly instead of storing in the database.

Comment: You know, I don't think I really need it - I want to give the user the ability to feed the pet whenever it is hungry, and make it not hungry. Is this something I should do with a helper function?

Comment: You could even just have a `last_fed_at` column (DateTime). That way you could have a `@creature.hungry?` method that's implemented like this: `last_fed_at > 5.hours.ago` (creature is only hungry if it hasn't been fed in 5 hours). Then you can have some logic: if @creature.hungry? then display FEED ME button. And FEED ME button just calls `@creature.feed` method which does `@creature.update_column(:last_fed_at, Time.now)`. And now @creature.hungry? is false because its last_fed_at was updated to now. Does that make sense?

Comment: That's a really good idea - would I put that in the view?

Comment: In the view, you'd put the `if @creature.hungry? then display <FEED BUTTON>`. The <FEED BUTTON> would point to the `CreaturesController#feed` action. The `feed` action could have the code `if @c = current_user.creatures.find(params[:id]) && @c.feed then redirect_to(@c, notice: "Creature was fed!")`. I obviously don't have much room in this comment but I hope you get the picture.

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track using model callbacks, however models don't have access to the `param` hash - its available to controllers.

The model already knows the value of it's own attributes, so you don't need to get them from params.  The controller I imagine is updating `feed_me`.

Also you shouldn't need to declare `feed_me` as an `attr_accessor` assuming it is backed by a database column.

You can change `before_save` to:

```
def feed
  if self.feed_me
    self.hungry = false
  end
end
```

In your controller, I imagine you'd do something like:

```
def update
  pet = Pet.find(params[:id])
  pet.feed_me = params[:feed_me]

  if pet.save
    redirect_to pet_path(pet)
  else
    flash[:notice] = 'Error saving pet'
    render :edit
  end
end
```

Comment: Here's what the controller looks like now: ```def update
    creature = Creature.find(params[:id])
    creature.feed_me = params[:feed_me]
    creature.hungry = params[:hungry]
    respond_to do |format|
      if @creature.update(creature_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @creature, notice: 'Creature was successfully updated. #{params[:feed]}' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @creature.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end```

Comment: I also updated the model as you suggested - I'm confused about when the feed is actually being called now. Would I do that from the controller?

Comment: If you have a 'before_save :feed' in your model now as Michael suggested, it get's called in the process of saving the model - initially triggered in your controller when you call @creature.update.

Comment: The strange thing is that it doesn't update, and I've gotten strange things when I try to inspect it. When I try to creature[:name].inspect , I get the name. When I try creature[:feed_me].inspect , I get nil, but when I try to params.inspect, I get this hash: ```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"patch", "authenticity_token"=>"kqboasdfasdfasdf=", "creature"=>{"name"=>"Bob", "hungry"=>"1", "feed_me"=>"1", "mood"=>"lazy"}, "commit"=>"Update Creature", "action"=>"update", "controller"=>"creatures", "id"=>"1"}```

Comment: Looks like you should be using `params[:creature][:hungry]` and `params[:creature][:feed_me]` (all params related to the creature model will be held within the `:creature` key of the `params` hash.

Comment: ok,to make things even more messed up, further research indicates I am somehow not setting boolean values from the update form. That's probably why the rest of it doesn't work. Now, to figure that out.

Comment: params[:creature][:hungry] does work, phew. Nothing like debugging in a system you don't know very well. :)

Comment: The good news is it for some reason lets me set hungry, but not feed_me

Comment: ok, when I RAISE creature.feed_me after having checked it in the view, it evaluates to true, but it somehow never saves as such.

Comment: ok, I figured it out. Because it's before_save, the model is getting its value from the database, and the database is set to false.

Comment: I got it - I reset the value in the controller, using the params: ```   creature = Creature.find(params[:id])
    creature.feed_me = params[:creature][:feed_me]
    if creature.feed_me == true
      params[:creature][:hungry]=false
    end```